# Как перевести в двоичную СС числа не помещающиеся в Unsigned Long Long?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки, системы-счисления

Мне нужно найти в строке числа и перевести их в двоичную СС (они сначала в десятичной СС)

Некоторые числа, когда достаешь их из строки банально не влезают в Unsigned Long Long (самый крупный тип в C++) и приходятся юзать Длинную Арифметику.

Вопрос: Как из строки перевести десятичные числа в двоичную СС не прибегая к её перевода в целочисленный тип?

К примеру, число `99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999` нужно перевести в 2 СС и ответом на него будет: `11100111110100110100110001100100101010011100100001011101010001000110000011011011101111001010100001110001100101101011011000010110000110001010010010111101001000010110011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111`

Нужно сделать что-то подобное

*Постарайтесь сделать код попроще, а то меня не поймут (мягко говоря) и просьба, непонятные моменты объяснить (по возможности)*

Comment: _Как из строки перевести десятичные числа в двоичную СС не прибегая к её перевода в целочисленный тип?_ - "Перевод в целочисленный тип" это и есть перевод в двоичную систему счисления, так что без этого никак.

Comment: Ну так и переводите. Покажите что сделали, объясните какая проблема с вашим кодом. А если вы рассчитываете что вам просто на халяву задание сделают, то это не сюда.

Comment: А как бы вы без компьютера стали такой перевод делать, имея только бумагу и ручку?

Comment: Что значит, "...а  то меня не поймут..."? Вас уже не понимают...

Comment: Сделайте двоичное сложение и сдвиг произвольно длинных двоичных цепочек. Далее, как обычно в цикле по цифрам: `Sum *= 10` (это 2 сдвига + сложение), `Sum += n` (n - очередная цифра).

Comment: "сделать код попроще, а то" - может, еще и Вашим почерком его написать, и с ошибками?

Comment: @Artem С какой стати Вы уничтожили текст вопроса? Вернул назад.

Answer (score 4):

Для перевода записи числа N из системы счисления с основанием A в систему счисления с основанием B можно предложить как минимум три метода:

1. **Метод деления с остатком**

   Последовательно делим число N на число B. Остаток каждого деления соответствует последовательным цифрам записи числа в СС с основанием B, в направлении от младших к старшим.

   Такой способ перевода ориентирован на использование вычислителя, оптимизированного для работы с представлениями чисел в СС с основанием A.
2. **Метод "жадного" вычитания**

   Находим максимальное число i, такое что B<sup>i</sup> <= N. Затем находим максимальное число k, такое что kB<sup>i</sup> <= N. Тогда k - это i-тая цифра записи числа в СС с основанием B. Вычитаем kB<sup>i</sup> из N, повторяем. ("Пропущенные" цифры равны 0.)

   Такой способ перевода тоже ориентирован на использование вычислителя, оптимизированного для работы с представлениями чисел в СС с основанием A.

   (Способы 1 и 2 - это способы, которые обычно использует человек при переводе "на бумажке" **из** десятичной записи **в** записи в других СС.)
3. **Метод сложения и сдвига**

   Представляем значение A в СС с основанием B. Обнуляем аккумулятор. Затем в направлении от старших к младшим: переводим  каждую индивидуальную цифру записи N в представление в СС с основанием B. Домножаем аккумулятор на A и прибавляем к аккумулятору полученную цифру.

   Такой способ перевода лучше всего подходит при использовании вычислителя, оптимизированного для работы с представлениями в СС с основанием B. (Аналогичный способ можно построить и для перевода в направлении от младших к старшим).

   Другими словами, если у вас есть число `abcd`, записанное в системе счисления с основанием A, то вычислив

   aA<sup>3</sup> + bA<sup>2</sup> + cA + d = ((aA + b)A + c)A + d

   при помощи вычислителя, работающего с представлениями в СС с основанием B, вы получите искомое представление.

   (Способ 3 - это способ, который обычно использует человек при переводе "на бумажке" **в** десятичную запись **из** записи в других СС.)

В вашем случае, из-за размера чисел, с которыми вам придется работать, вам понадобится использовать/реализовывать длинную арифметику, т.е. реализовывать самостоятельный вычислитель. Так как такие вычислители скорее всего будут внутренне работать с двоичным представлением чисел, вам подойдет именно способ номер 3. Однако если вы найдете/реализуете длинную арифметику, работающую именно с десятичными представлениями (хотя бы концептуально), то в вашем распоряжении будут и методы 1 и 2.

---

Все или почти все необходимые для решения этой задачи "вручную" примитивы наличествуют, например, здесь

[Сумма цифр числа 100!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/916591/%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-100)

Answer (score 1):

1. Проверяем чётность, запоминаем бит в последовательность результата
2. Делим число на 2 - это довольно просто
3. Если число стало нулём, то переворачиваем получившуюся последовательность и выводим,
   иначе продолжаем с шага 1

Код полностью: https://ideone.com/Qm8qfh

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  for (string s; cin >> s; )
  {
    size_t l=0, n=s.length();

    for (size_t q=0; q<n; ++q)
      s[q] -= '0';

    vector <bool> res;

    LOOP:
    {
      res.push_back(s[n-1] & 1);

      for (int d=0, p; l<n; ++l)
        if (p=d?5:0, d=s[l]&1, (s[l]>>=1)+=p)
        {
          for (size_t q=l+1; q<n; ++q)
            p=d?5:0, d=s[q]&1, (s[q]>>=1)+=p;

          goto LOOP;
        }
    }

    copy(res.rbegin(), res.rend(), ostream_iterator<bool>(cout, ""));
    cout << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Думаете ТС сможет объяснить кому-либо, как *довольно просто*  выполняется деление числа пополам?