# Что происходит при выполнении (res * 10) + (*str - '0') в функции atoi на С

Tags: c, ascii

Самостоятельно пишу функцию atoi на языке C. Сама функция ниже. Не до конца понимаю что происходит в строчках `res = (res * 10) + (*str - '0')` и `res = (res * 10) - (*str - '0')`. Объясните пожалуйста по шагам?

```
int        ft_atoi(char *str)
{
  int res;
  int sign;

  res = 0;
  sign = 1;
  while (*str == '\n' || *str == ' ' || *str == '\t' || *str == '\r' ||
    *str == '\v' || *str == '\f')
      ++str;
  if (*str == '+' || *str == '-')
  {
    if (*str == '-')
      sign = 0;
      str++;
  }
  while ((*str) >= '0' && (*str) <= '9')
  {
    if (sign)
      res = (res * 10) + (*str - '0');
      else
        res = (res * 10) - (*str - '0');
      str++;
  }
  return (res);
}
```

Comment: "самостоятельно пишу и не понимаю" - как-то это странно звучит :) а по-существу, (*str - '0') вернет число от 0 до 9, если текущий символ в строке - это char  от '0' до '9'; ((res*10) + x) - умножить текущее значение res на 10 и добавить число в разряд единиц.

Comment: эту строчку взял из оригинальной функции :) спасибо большое за разъяснение!

Answer (score 4):

Спецификация языка С гарантирует, что символьные константы `'0'`, `'1'`,..., `'9'` имеют последовательные целочисленные значения (и именно в таком порядке). Это означает, что такие символьные значения можно легко преобразовать в целочисленные значения `0`, `1`,...,`9` (соответственно) путем вычитания из них значения `'0'`. Именно это свойство используется в вашем коде в подвыражении `(*str - '0')`.

Весь код в целом реализует подход номер 3 [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/930638/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%A1%D0%A1-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2-unsigned-long-long/930664#930664). То есть мы в цикле от старших цифр к младшим умножаем аккумулятор на 10 и прибавляем значение следующей цифры, умножаем и прибавляем, умножаем и прибавляем...