# Перевод числа в 8-ричную систему счисления

Tags: c++

Как перевести целое число N в восьмеричную систему?

например:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string xopa="";
    int n=53;
    for(;n;n>0)
    {
        if(n%2==1)
        {
            xopa="1"+xopa;
            n=n/2;
        }
        if(n%2==0)
        {
            xopa="0"+xopa;
            n=n/2;
        }
    }
    cout << xopa << endl;
}
```

Является двоичной системой

Comment: совсем никаких собственных идей?

Comment: http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread49517-page2.html#post260903

Comment: Способ 1 из списка: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/930664/182825

Answer (score 1):

Да притмерно как вы и написали, только символы надо брать из большего диаазона.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string xopa="";
    int n=53;
    for( ; n ; n/=8)
        xopa = char('0'+n%8) + xopa;
    cout << xopa << endl;
}
```

И еще - что вы хотели добиться своим `n>0` в заголовке цикла `for`?

Comment: xopa = char('0'+n%8) + xopa; то же самое, что и   xopa += char('0'+n%8) ; но второе и быстрее и  читабельней

Comment: @AR_Hovsepyan, не тоже самое. Задом наперёд. Но ваш вариант + разворот строки всё равно быстрее.